# Limit of a complex function used in probability theory

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-distributions

I saw a demonstration related to characteristic functions which states that:

\begin{equation}\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\{\lambda(e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1)-it\sqrt{\lambda}\}=-\frac{1}{2}t^2\end{equation}
and, similarly, that
\begin{equation}\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\bigg\{-\lambda\log\bigg(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\bigg)-it\sqrt{\lambda}\bigg\}=-\frac{1}{2}t^2\end{equation}

How could this be demonstrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are just Taylor expansions. For the first, write $$e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1=\frac{it}{\sqrt{\lambda}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{t^2}{\lambda}+o\left(\frac{1}\lambda\right).$$ It follows pretty quickly from that. The second can be calculated similarly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For both set $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ and use L'Hospital rule as $x\to0$.